How can I expand (a-b)^n, where a=1, b=u^2 and n is any number, lets say n=4
$$(a-b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$$
I just want to know how to write the expression out

$$(a-b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$$
The expression shows a shortcut where you use the binomial coefficients, these are found in Pascal's triangle, or you may compute $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.
$$\begin{align}(a-b)^0&=\color{red}{1}\\(a-b)^1&=\color{red}{1}a-\color{red}{1}b\\(a-b)^2&=\color{red}{1}a^2-\color{red}{2}ab+\color{red}{1}b^2\\(a-b)^3&=\color{red}{1}a^3-\color{red}{3}a^2b+\color{red}{3}ab^2-\color{red}{1}b^3\end{align}$$
If you let $a=1,b=u^2$ you get $$\begin{align}(1-u^2)^0&=\color{red}{1}\\(1-u^2)^1&=\color{red}{1}-\color{red}{1}u^2\\(1-u^2)^2&=\color{red}{1}-\color{red}{2}u^2+\color{red}{1}u^4\\(1-u^2)^3&=\color{red}{1}-\color{red}{3}u^2+\color{red}{3}u^4-\color{red}{1}u^6\end{align}$$

Thank you, but you clarify what is value of k here, because the lower limit of the sigma has k=0, but if we use k=0, the denominator will be 0

$0!=1$, so there is no dividing by zero. We want $n!=n\cdot (n-1)!$ to hold, let $n=1$ and we get $1!=1\cdot 0!$, that is, $0!=1$.

Thank you so much
